# How to get the full creadit number form paypalhere SDK named "ios-here-sdk-dist-master", I am getting "maskedCardNumber" instead of whole number

Tags: ios, paypal, magnetic-cards, cardreader, paypal-here

I have successfully integrated the paypal Swipe card SDK named"ios-here-sdk-dist-master". I am getting the card details like "maskedCardNumber, cardholderName, cardholderFirstName, cardholderLastName, expirationMonth, expirationYear, extraData, ksn, serial, asDictionary" except whole credit card number.

Note:- I am getting maskedCardNumber("4333XXXXXXXX3333") and I want whole number like "4333145785423333".

My Log

```
Main thread | PayPalHere: ROAM::onDecodeCompleted {
    cardholderName = "xxxxxxxxxx             ";
    encTrack = 84298C945E6B142xxxxxxxxxxxxx6AA17F97;
    expiryDate = xxxx;
    formatID = 29;
    ksn = 4029xxxxxC2508E0000D;
    maskedPAN = 4333XXXXXXXX3333;
    partialTrack = "xxxxxxxxxx             ";
    track1Status = 0;
    track2Status = 0;
}
```

SDK:- Downloaded from Github
For more details click  [enter link description here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/).

Comment: Probably you are not supposed to get the whole credit card number. What would you use it for? Those 8 numbers, amongst other parameters, are surely enough to uniquely identify your customers to you.

Comment: Hi "dreab" I want to save the card details for feature purpose / i want to made the payment through web side not from mobile apps

Comment: The PayPal SDK not allow you to access the user card detail. If you try with another ways,Before that you have to check the security of storing card detail.

Comment: Storing the credit card would require your app and server to be PCI DSS compliant and Paypal can't know if your app is compliant so they can't give you the card number

Comment: Thanks guys, but i want to send the card details to web for transaction? Or want i use any another SDK to get the car details? And one more thing i get the card details using PAYPAL Card scanner SDK.